# How to create Windows Event Log script?

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log, splunk

I have an environment where a Windows Server is located. I need to generate specific security events that will be sent to a Splunk instance, i.e. 6x Login Failed then Login Success - that is just one usecase.

Ideally, I would like to write a script which will periodically ( every hour let's say ) insert these custom fake events into eventlogs and therefore - they will be sent to my Splunk instance where it looks like that this has happened ( event in reality, it hasn't had happened, because there is no-one in that environment )

I know exactly what events I need, what I don't know how to automatically create them.

In order words - I need to generate fake Windows event data so it looks like they are from some real environment.

If somebody could point me to some article or draft how can I write that script - I suppose it should be easy script - or maybe use different approach I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/20/how-to-use-powershell-to-write-to-event-logs/) for writing to the event log. You will be able to create custom event from a custom source. But I don't think you can create fake events from source owned by the system, so you may need to configure `Splunk` to pick up the custom source.

```
New-EventLog –LogName system –Source "App1" 
Write-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "App1" -EventID 1234 -EntryType Error -Message "Some Error message"
```